# Is EC2Config Service is supposed to present in instance launched from custom created AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-opsworks, aws-cli

I am trying to create AMI with my application installed for W2K8 and W2K12 Server. For this purpose, I have followed the below steps for both :

1. Launch the required instance from the available instances . For example, Windows 2008 Server base.
2. Once the instance is up and running, I am checking the version of EC2Config service. If new update is available, I am updating it.
3. I am turning On the 'Automatic Windows Update' and installing the updates.
4. Then, I am installing my application and do required changes.
5. Now my machine is ready. As last step, I starting EC2Config Service wizard.
6. On EC2Config Wizard, in 'Image' tab, I am enabling "Random" in "Administrator password".
7. Then , I am clicking on button - "Shutdown with Sysprep".
8. With Sysprep config done, machine is down and I am creating image of it. Let say image name is 'W2K8-Image'

Now, my question is - When I create new instance from image 'W2K8-image' and launch it, EC2Config service are still present.
So, is it suppose to be present on this instance? If not, what are the setting need to be done to remove it while creating AMI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you not want the EC2Config service?  I think you are misunderstanding its intent.  It should generally be running on all instances, as it provides enhancements to a running instance in EC2.  It is not just for making new images.

Think of it like VMware Tools in a VMware guest, for example.